# Bookshelf: query builder: how to use like operator with json column?

Tags: json, postgresql, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I'm using bookshelf with postgresql database

Information is a column of type json.

I want to retrieve all column that are like '%pattern%'
With sql query i use

```
select * from table where information::text like '%pattern%';
```

I want to do that with bookshelf query builder

```
model.query(function(qb) {
  qb.where('information', 'LIKE', '%pattern%')
}).fetch()
```

But it didn't work and i can't find how to do it in [bookshelf docs](https://bookshelfjs.org/tutorials.html)

Any idea?

Comment: Why make a text search in a structured data format like JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part here is, although you might think that JSON (and JSONB) columns are text, they aren't! So there's no way to do a `LIKE` comparison on one. Well, there is, but you'd have to convert it to a string first:

```
SELECT * FROM wombats WHERE information #>> '{}' LIKE '%pattern%';
```

which is a really terrible idea, please don't do that! As [@GMB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10676716/gmb) points out in the comments, JSON is a structured format that is far more powerful. Postgres is great at handling JSON, so just ask it for what you need. Let's say your value is in a JSON property named `description`:

```
SELECT * FROM wombats
  WHERE (information->'description')::TEXT
  LIKE '%pattern%';
```

Here, even though we've identified the correct property in our JSON object, it comes out as type `JSON`: we still have to cast it to `::TEXT` before comparing it with a string using `LIKE`. The Bookshelf/Knex version of all this would look like:

```
model
  .query(function(qb) {
    const keyword = "pattern";
    qb.whereRaw(`(information->'description')::TEXT LIKE '%${keyword}%'`)
  })
  .fetch();
```

Apparently this part of the raw query cannot be parameterized (in Postgres, at least) so the string substitution in JavaScript is required. This means you should be extra careful with where that string comes from (ie only use a limited subset, or sanitise before use) as you're bypassing Knex's usual protections.

Comment: is there a typo in your example, it didn't work either
 qb.whereRaw(`user.informtation->'description')::TEXT LIKE '%?%'`, 'pattern');

Comment: Why, yes there was :D (see, this is why you shouldn't copy and paste!) I've edited to add the trailing quote. Note that everything in the first argument is a string.

Comment: still not working i even add parenthesis i think we miss one

model
  .query(function(qb) {
      qb.whereRaw(`(information->'description')::TEXT LIKE '%?%'`, 'pattern')
    })
  .fetch();
here is the error message
{"name":"error","length":130,"severity":"ERROR","code":"08P01","file":"postgres.c","line":"1516","routine":"exec_bind_message"}

Comment: Yep, I went right back and tried it with Bookshelf and it doesn't like it too much at all! Edited to provide a modified solution, sorry for the runaround.

Comment: yes it works now with small change  qb.whereRaw(`(information)::TEXT LIKE '%${keyword}%'`)

Comment: Well sure, you can do that but again you're converting the entire JSON object into text and searching it like a string. What you want is to choose the name of the JSON property you're actually trying to check, like `information->foo` or `information-bar` and do a comparison on that.